# Docker copy command can not find the dotnet publish release

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a Docker image for ASP NET Core (2.1.2) multi project application. It is giving the following error when copy the release from output folder to the current location.

> COPY failed: stat out: file does not exist

In my log I can see the dotnet restore getting done without any error and so the `Copy ..`. There is no error in "dotnet publish either".

I'm not sure if I'm using the right version of dot net core MCR for the base image and sdk but the version (2.1) i'm using is not giving me any error. Also, I will be interested in knowing if I can look into the `-o out` folder content?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build
WORKDIR .

COPY *.sln ./
COPY ./APIProject/APIProject.csproj ./APIProject/
COPY ./ClassLibraryProject1/ClassLibraryProject1.csproj ./ClassLibraryProject1/
COPY ./ClassLibraryProject2/ClassLibraryProject2.csproj ./ClassLibraryProject2/
COPY ./ClassLibraryProject3/ClassLibraryProject3.csproj ./ClassLibraryProject1/
COPY ./TestProject/TestProject.csproj ./TestProject/

RUN echo -e 'dotnet restore start'
RUN dotnet restore
RUN echo -e 'dotnet restore end'

COPY . .

RUN echo -e 'dotnet publish start'
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
RUN echo -e 'dotnet publish end'

RUN dir

FROM base
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "APIProject.dll"]
```

Following is the docker output log

```
-e 'dotnet restore start'
Removing intermediate container 27f83064981c
 ---> 443956516af8
Step 17/26 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 122fe37b2940
  Restore completed in 235.21 ms for C:\APIProject\APIProject.csproj.
  Restore completed in 7.46 sec for C:\ClassLibraryProject1\ClassLibraryProject1.csproj.
  Restore completed in 7.75 sec for C:\ClassLibraryProject2\ClassLibraryProject2.csproj.
  Restore completed in 1.38 sec for C:\ClassLibraryProject3\ClassLibraryProject3.csproj.
  Restore completed in 14.07 sec for C:\TestProject\TestProject.csproj.
Removing intermediate container 122fe37b2940
 ---> d939238febc4
Step 18/26 : RUN echo -e 'dotnet restore end'

-e 'dotnet publish start'
Removing intermediate container e325c0b0cd37
 ---> 14282d19c0d6
Step 21/26 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
 ---> Running in d050d6dda0c6
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.37902+b5aaefc9f for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 6.25 sec for C:\ClassLibraryProject1\ClassLibraryProject1.csproj.
  Restore completed in 6.37 sec for C:\ClassLibraryProject2\ClassLibraryProject2.csproj.
  Restore completed in 252.81 ms for C:\ClassLibraryProject3\ClassLibraryProject3.csproj.
  Restore completed in 687.66 ms for C:\APIProject\APIProject.csproj.
  
  ClassLibraryProject1 -> C:\ClassLibraryProject1\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\ClassLibraryProject1.dll
  ClassLibraryProject2 -> C:\ClassLibraryProject2\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\ClassLibraryProject2.dll
  ClassLibraryProject3 -> C:\ClassLibraryProject3\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\ClassLibraryProject3.dll
  ClassLibraryProject3 -> C:\ClassLibraryProject3\out\
  ClassLibraryProject2 -> C:\ClassLibraryProject2\out\
  ClassLibraryProject1 -> C:\ClassLibraryProject1\out\
  APIProject -> C:\APIProject\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\APIProject.dll
  APIProject -> C:\APIProject\out\
  TestProject -> C:\TestProject\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\TestProject.dll
  TestProject -> C:\TestProject\out\
Removing intermediate container d050d6dda0c6
 ---> 528d70e94dbc
Step 22/26 : RUN echo -e 'dotnet publish end'
 ---> Running in 4bea2d79d622
-e 'dotnet publish end'

Removing intermediate container 4bea2d79d622
 ---> e9c1b838f678
Step 23/26 : FROM base
 ---> 2768a58cbbd3
Step 24/26 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in ae4e7425fc68
Removing intermediate container ae4e7425fc68
 ---> b40ca00d0be2
Step 25/26 : COPY --from=build /out .
```

Comment: Could you validate if /out folder exist?

Comment: I'm new to the docker and don't really know how to inspect the /out folder hence asked in my question. Will you please explain where I should look for it @JRichardsz?

Comment: `COPY --from=build /out .` expect that /out folder exist on  intermediate stage called **build**. Since docker is linux, you can inspect after the build just trying to print its content with:  `RUN ls -la`

Comment: run it in your dockerfile. Basically the error is for example: `copy from c:/foo/out d://bar`. One of these folder does not exist **inside** of container. Is your app a web or api or a desktop app?

Comment: Thanks @JRichardsz. I've managed to get down to the problem. I was missing `/` before `out` in my 'RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /out' command. Your advise of checking the out folder existence really helped so I'm upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried locally and I fixed with:

- in build

  - change this `WORKDIR .`
  - for this `WORKDIR /tmp/app`
- in last step

  - change this `COPY --from=build /out .`
  - to this `COPY --from=build /tmp/app/out .`

### explanation

When you use dot in `WORKDIR .` you are telling to docker that use `/` as location. This location is known as **the root** and is not recommended to create folder at this level.

Then the command `RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out` is not able to create the **out** folder at the root **/**.

But if you use any other location in WORKDIR, out folder is created as expected.

**before restore**

[image]

**after restore**

[image]

**after publish**

[image]

### Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build
WORKDIR /tmp/app

COPY . .
RUN ls -la
RUN dotnet restore
RUN ls -la

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
RUN ls -la

FROM base
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /tmp/app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "APIProject.dll"]
```

Sample entcore code from: https://github.com/jrichardsz/dotnet-core-hello-world

### advice

- If docker says you that some file or folder does not exist, debug it using `RUN ls -la` before and after the error